# OpenSSL Phantom Non-Existing Versions

Tags: openssl

No ofense to anyone but I'm extremey confused. On the OpenSSL website's [SourceFiles](http://www.openssl.org/source/)
section states that the newest version is 1.0.0e.

To quote the page

> 4040229 Sep  6 15:21:26 2011 openssl-1.0.0e.tar.gz (MD5) (SHA1) (PGP
>   sign)  [LATEST]

It even screams saying "LATEST".

Yet on the [ChangeLog](http://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html) at the OpenSSL website it talks about versions that don't seem to exist. For example, it talks about:
Changes between 1.0.1 and 1.1.0
Changes between 1.0.0f and 1.0.1
Changes between 1.0.0e and 1.0.0f

The strange thing is that none of these versions with the exception of 1.0.0e seem to exist.

The reasson I am asking clarification and help in this issue is not because I want to complain about the OpenSSL website but because I am looking for a feature (AES XTS) which seems to have been added in version 1.1.0

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I've looked thoroughly on the OpenSSL website and Google and can't seem to find these phantom ghost version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those versions are in development and haven't been released because they aren't finished.  The [source code page](http://www.openssl.org/source/) says at the top:

> Tarballs containing a snapshot of the latest development version can
>   be found under ftp://ftp.openssl.org/snapshot/.

That's where you'll find these unreleased versions:

```
openssl-0.9.8-stable-SNAP-<date>.tar.gz
   Daily snapshots, 0.9.8 stable branch.

openssl-1.0.0-stable-SNAP-<date>.tar.gz
   Daily snapshots, 1.0.0 stable branch.

openssl-1.0.1-stable-SNAP-<date>.tar.gz
   Daily snapshots, 1.0.1 stable branch.

openssl-SNAP-<date>.tar.gz
   Daily snapshots, development version (1.1.0-dev).

openssl-fips-2.0-test-<date>.tar.gz
   Daily snapshots, FIPS 2.0 modules test tarball.
```